# Save a file to a different folder using php?

Tags: php, file, save

I want to know if it is possible to save a file to a different folder once it is opened.  My current logic is -

```
$myfile = $_POST['file']; // gets path of (in this case an image)
$size = getimagesize($myfile);  //for some reason I get an error message when this fails
// I'm assuming there is a better way of determining if the file is an image file or not.
if($size)
{
    //save file to said file path
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if($size)
{
    copy($myfile, $newfile); //$newfile - with full path!
}
```